# how to get the value and store in the page in jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a function to select the row and that comes the selected value in the alert box. Now i want that value to store in the page instead of alert box.

Here is the function,

```
var generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected = function(id, to_s) { alert(id + to_s)}
```

It brings the selected value into the alert box. Istead of alert the value i want to display the value into the page like a label or anything. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var add = function(id, to_s) {
   $(id).html(to_s);
}
```

You might also want `append`, `prepend` or [similar](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

You basically need to call the function with *where* you want to text to be. Say you have a `span` somewhere on your page with a `class="placeholder"`. No you can call `add("span.placeholder", "Some text that should be displayed in the span")`.

`id` can be any element on your page.
`to_s` is any valid string or element that should be placed into `id` from above.

Comment: am new to jquery... can u explain in detail. I want to display the string into the html page like into the textbox or label or anything?

Comment: instead of showing text like "Some text that should be displayed in the span". Is it possible to hide that span and enable after we clicked???

Comment: Yes it is but this is beyond the scope of this question. Either open up a new one but be sure to read the [API](http://api.jquery.com/) before hand.

Answer (score 1):

just use jQuery [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function:

```
function putStringInDiv(id, to_s){ $("'#"+id+"'").text(to_s); }
```

the id should be your div's id. like

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

then calling the function will assign the text into the div:

```
putStringInDiv('myDiv','some text here');
```

Comment: am new to jquery... can u explain in detail. I want to display the string into the html page like into the textbox or label or anything?

Comment: Thanks you are helping me.. But its very complicated for me... :(  I have an id of the text field `section_question` in the html page. so, when we click the link, this text field display the selected value. The onClick id is `generic_lookup_Enr_Rds_Section2009_selected` .